# Return element I've just appended

Tags: jquery, dom

```
function createLink(){
    var elementString = "<a class='my_link' href='#'> link </a>";
    $('#display').append(elementString);
}

for(var i = 0; i > 10; i++){
    createLink();
    var element = $('my_link')[i];
    console.log( element );
}
```

Whenever I run my loop, I get the following in the console:

```
<a class='my_link' href='#'> link </a>
```

30 times, which is exactly what I want. However, I'd like to be able to do this:

```
for(var i = 0; i > 10; i++){
    var element = createLink();
    console.log( element );
}
```

and have `<a class='my_link' href='#'> link </a>` logged thirty times. What do I need my `createLink()` function to return in order to do this?

```
return $('#display').append(elementString);
```

doesn't work, for example

Comment: the reason jQuery chaining works is methods typically return the elements that were passed into them from the left side, not the arguments of the method

Comment: I get you, sounds like a plan. So there's nothing wrong with `var element = $('my_link')[i];` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
var $element = $("<a class='my_link' href='#'> link </a>");
$('#display').append($element);
return $element;
```

Comment: I think it'd be better if the function didn't append anything and simply returned the element, leave the for loop to append the element... think MVC

Comment: @scrowler Could you explain that a bit more, maybe in an answer? I didn't think MVC could apply to javascript... Regardless, you mean I should stick with `var element = $('my_link')[i];`?

Comment: It's not answer worthy, just a note. With the MVC concept you leave all the presentation to the view. Think of your function as a model, it's in a way dealing with data and returning it, the line where you call the function should then append it to the DOM.

Comment: @scrowler OKay, and what would be the controller?

Comment: I suppose in theory the code that calls the model would be your controller - you'd then pass the data the model returns to the view to be formatted - essentially what "append" is doing I guess... it's just an example, don't think too far into it

Comment: Okay, thanks. There's mountains of resources on how to use js/jquery but not too much on design patterns. I just package related functions into objects, that's it really :/ Do you reckon that's okay, or is there a a consensus on how to organize, and if so, is there a book or site you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function createLink() {
    var elementString = $.parseHTML("<a class='my_link' href='#'> link </a>"
                        , document, false);
        $("#display").append(elementString);
        return ( $(".my_link").is("*") ? $(".my_link").eq(0) : null )
};

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     var element = createLink();
     console.log(element);
};
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/DkY6D/